# In spite of the fact that I have set width, why my image gets shrinked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set width and height but it ignores this, and shows as original size.
Why??? Bootstrap Css is preventing or something???

```
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <img alt="2011-08-16_20.01.51" class="img-polaroid" height="100" src="/system/user_avatars/1/thumb/2011-08-16_20.01.51.jpg?1355911975" width="100" />
            </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) CSS overrides the `height` attribute (and, depending on browser and its mode, the `width` attribute as well). It sets `height: auto` and `width: auto\9`. CSS settings override the HTML attributes, so you need to use CSS to override the Bootstrap settings. In inline CSS, you would use

```
 <img ... style="width: 100px; height: 100px" ...>
```

but you can also use a style sheet in a `style` element or an external style sheet. Bootstrap code uses the `img` selector, so it is easy to beat it by the cascade rules.